# SQL Server select column while inserting

Tags: sql, sql-server

This question is a part of an insert statement in which I am trying to select a value from another value that can be inserted into a column.

For example in my table OnlineServers, I have columns:

```
ID, ServerID, OnlineSince
```

In my second table ImportServers, I have columns with the data (The lines after NewYork and Paris are actually empty):

```
ImportServerName
NewYork

London
Paris

Tokyo
```

This question is related to SQL Server.

In my third table, which is a look-up table called ServerLookup, I have these columns with data:

```
ID, ServerName
0   Not specified
1   NewYork
2   London
3   Tokyo
4   Munich
5   Salzburg
```

Question: I want to have an sql statement which can select ID '0' from ServerLookup table if the value of the column ImportServerName is empty.

What I have so far is:

```
insert into OnlineServers (ServerID, OnlineSince)
select
(
    select ID
    from ServerLookup
    where ServerLookup.ServerName = ImportServers.ServerName
       or ServerLookup.ServerName = ''
),
GETDATE()
from ImportServers
```

The problem I am facing is if the server name is matched, it also returns an extra row with empty server name.

How can I fix this problem.

Thanks

PS: Forgive me if there is any typo in the code

Comment: what value do you  have against `ID= 0'  do you have null value or do you have `not specified` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO OnlineServers
SELECT CASE ImportServerName 
    WHEN '' THEN 0
    ELSE ID
END AS ServerID, GetDate()
FROM ImportedServers s 
LEFT JOIN ServerLookup l on s.ImportedServerName = l.ServerName;
```

This should do it. You `LEFT JOIN` so you get every record from ImportedServers and use `CASE` to get 0 where ImportServerName is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT FIRST(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Limiting the return to the first match, also, shoudl teh from not be inside the select brackets?

```
    select FIRST(ID)
        from ServerLookup
        where ServerLookup.ServerName = ImportServers.ServerName
           or ServerLookup.ServerName = ''
from ImportServers)
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your problem correctly try something like this

```
insert into OnlineServers (ServerID, OnlineSince)
select TOP(1) ID ,GETDATE() 
   from ServerLookup
   inner join ImportServers
    on ServerLookup.ServerName = ImportServers.ServerName
     Where ServerLookup.ServerName = ''
```